# Program is taking way longer than expected, is it running properly?

Tags: c, ubuntu

not sure this is the right place...
I am running a brute-force code to solve an asymmetric traveler sales problem.
It has 17 cities, one is fixed, so it would have 16! (> 20 trillions) permutations to check.

```
unsigned long TotalCost(unsigned long *Matrix, short *Path, short 
Dimention)
{
    unsigned long result = 0;
    unsigned long Cost;
    int iD;

    for (iD = 1; iD <= Dimention; iD++)
    {
            Cost = Matrix[Dimention*Path[iD - 1] + Path[iD]];
            if (Cost > 0)
            {
                result = result + Cost;
            }
            else
            {
                return 4099999999;
            }

    }
    return result;
}

void swapP(short *x, short *y)
{
    short temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(unsigned long *Matrix, short Dimention, unsigned long *CurrentMin, short *PerPath, short **MinPath, short l, short r)
{
short i;
unsigned long CCost;

if (l == r)
{
    CCost = TotalCost(Matrix, PerPath, Dimention);
    if (CCost < (*CurrentMin))
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= Dimention; i++)
        {
            (*MinPath)[i] = PerPath[i];
        }
        (*CurrentMin) = CCost;
        PrintResults(Matrix, PerPath, Dimention, 2);
    }
}
else
{
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
        swapP((PerPath+l), (PerPath+i));
        permute(Matrix, Dimention, CurrentMin, PerPath, MinPath, l+1, r);
        swapP((PerPath+l), (PerPath+i)); //backtrack
    }
}
}

int main (void)
{
// The ommited code here, allocs memory for the matrix, HcG and HrGR array
// it also initializes them

   permute(Matrix, Dimention, &TotalMin, HcG, &HrGR, 1, Dimention - 1);
}
```

I tested the above code for an instance of five cities and it returned successfully as expected in a few milliseconds.
For the 17 cities, i initially thought it would take a few hours to solve, and then a couple days. It is running for 4 days now and i'm beginning to suspect the program, for some reason, is no longer running, like it's frozen.
I'm not getting any errors, but it's taking way longer than i expected, the program prints the total cost and the path every time it finds a path with lower cost, but it stopped printing half an hour since it started.

I am using ubuntu 18.04, the program is "running" on terminal, the system monitor tells Memory: N/A, does that mean it's not using memory?
It also tells CPU: 6%, can i increase it?
Is there a way to check if it is running properly? Or estimate how long it will take to finish?
I'm so unsure about it's integrity that i think i should stop the process, but at the same time i really wanted to see the results.

Comment: With the program which runs recursively for days, have you considered the possibility of stack overflow ?

Comment: There's really no good way to tell, as it's very dependent on your specific machine. However, it does sound like it probably hung somewhere along the way. If you want to make it faster, you might be able to do some multithreading with pthreads.

Comment: I considered, but then i expected to get an error message of some kind. I also expect the stack to be a maximum of 16?

Comment: If you output the loop value in the first level of recursion, that will give a very good idea how long it's going to take. You'll also know if it has hung when the expected next cue does not appear.

Comment: Supposing “a few milliseconds” is three, and five cities require testing 4! permutations while 17 cities require 16! permutations, then a direct scaling to 17 cities requires (3•10^-3) / 4! • 16! seconds, which is about 2.6 billion seconds, or 83 years.

Comment: The fact your program is getting only 6% CPU time suggests it is waiting for memory swapping (using too much virtual memory) or waiting for other resources. However, you have not shown a [mcve]. You should show a [mcve].

Comment: 83 years is a little long ahhaha, i will follow @Daniel Goldfarb suggestion and kill the process, add prints in the middle so i can have a feedback of what's happening.
thank you all for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only glanced through your code, but I have done things like this many times in the past.  My general approach for this is as follows (although it adds a small cost) ...

1. add a print statement in a way (perhaps with a mod counter) that you would expect the print to come out approximately once every 2 to 3 minutes.  Include some information in the print so that you can tell how far along your simulation is progressing.  (note, among that information you probably want to be sure to print out variables that, if they get trashed, could cause infinite looping, for example "Dimention" (which you have misspelled btw)
2. I would personally not have jumped from 5 cities to 17.  Rather 5 to 7, then maybe 9 or 10 ... just to confirm all is working and to get an idea how much time increase to expect with your particular CPU.

Finally, in the situation you are in now, is it possible to get another window and run "ps" to see if your job is getting any CPU time?   If not, my approach would be to kill it and implement as I described above.  HTH.

Note also, the code you have omitted (memory allocation, etc) *is critical*:  the code as written has the potential to go out of bounds, and possibly *not* crash (if only slightly out of bounds) but rather end up trashing variables (depending on memory layout) that could (as mentioned above) create an infinite or near-infinite loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "ps" will do a search, i thought about accessing the program memory and check the current value of the vector to see how far it has ran, but i don't think the OS will allow me to do that.

Comment: Open another terminal (if you can) and run "ps -ef | grep '<your job>".  It will show you how much CPU it has used so far.  If you run it twice a couple seconds apart you should see the CPU time increase.  If you job is running in the background you can run ps on the same terminal.

Comment: Protip: If your program is named `traveler`, grep ps's output with `grep [t]raveler`.  That way `grep` won't find its own invocation.

Comment: If the job is hung, it will not be getting CPU time, and you can kill it.  Unfortunately if it is getting CPU time then (without print statements or any other way to see progress) you won't know if it is progressing or looping aimlessly.  If you can't prove its making progress, if it were me I'd cut my losses and start again with the approach outlined in my answer (I have in fact cut my losses so to speak many times when I thought I could otherwise get away without the print statement approach).

Comment: It outputs:
bruno    28875 27102 99 out06 pts/0    3-21:14:28 ./HeuristicaRefinamento
with no headers, i assume 99 is the CPU time, i'll follow your advice, kill the process and add the print statement.
thanks for your time.

Comment: I should have mentioned, run `ps -ef | head `  just before running `ps -ef | grep <jobname>` so that you can see the column names.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb Or if you really want to show off, pipe it into `sed -n -e 1p -e '/jobname/p'` (or maybe even `/[j]obname/p`) instead.